# C++, volatile и strict aliasing rules

Tags: c++, volatile, strict-aliasing

Подскажите, пожалуйста, законно ли использование спецификатора `volatile` для локального *обхода* требований строгих псевдонимов?

Например:

```
void do_something(volatile void* const _data)
{
    volatile A* const a = (volatile A* const)(_data);
    // Что-то делаем с содержимым памяти через представление a.

    volatile B* const b = (volatile B* const)(_data);
    // Что-то делаем с содержимым памяти через представление b.

    // Снова что-то делаем с содержимым памяти через a и b.
}
```

Я подозреваю, что `volatile` не предназначен для этого, но полной уверенности у меня нет.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186137/does-volatile-permits-type-punning-with-unions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `reinterpret_cast` не может использоваться для избавления от `volatile` квалификатора (для этого нужен `const_cast`)
2. Требования для алиасинга устанавливаются для действия доступа к объекту, а путь получения ссылки или указателя на него для осуществления доcтупа на эти требования никак не влияет.

Answer (score 1):

Нет конечно, volatile не имеет никакого отношения к правилам aliasing'а.